# Android app button onClick advice

Tags: android, button, onclick

I am trying to create my first Android app and need some help.

Basically the app has a webview which loads a URL which works fine but I have a button under it that I want when pressed to open a different URL in the webview window.

I cannot figure out how to tell the button to do this.

This is my first app so apologise if the answer is very simple.

Many thanks in advance

Jay

Comment: Please tell if the button is inside the webview (and so done with html) or it's a classic android widget.

Comment: it's outside the webview I think I done it with a widget but not 100% sure im still learning, how can I tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the button is inside the webView...

create a new class which extends webviewclient and add this to your web view like this.. , it will load the remaining urls in the same web view.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());


private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

take a look at this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) too....

if it is outside webView.. then

```
Button webButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonId);
webButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
         mWebView.loadUrl(urltoload);
  }
});
```

mWebView is the web view in your xml.you need to get access to it. Put the above code in `onCreate` of your activity after you do `setContentView()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the link but the button is outside the webview, underneath it, will the code you provided still work?

Comment: great thanks for that, how do I assign this to a button press?

Comment: Thanks for your help I appreciate it but im confused, here is my .java.  EDIT, it wont let me post the code, to long. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    webView.loadUrl(yourUrl);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, where do I put this under main.xml?

Comment: inside your oncreate, after you initialize your button and webview variables